# Does startactivity method not call onCreate method of the intended activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that goes from Activity A(Launcher activity) to Activity B to emailIntent. When I return from the email Activity it simply resumes Activity A. So I tried calling the email activity with a startActivityforResult() method. and in onActivity result I created an intent to launch activity A. But this too just resumes Activity A and the onCreate method is not called. what can be done? Please help.

Here is my code for reference.

```
try {
        startActivityForResult(emailIntent,123);
        finish();
        Log.i("Finished sending email.", "");
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Final.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==123){
        Intent startintent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(startintent);
    }
```

Comment: is your `onActivityResult` method in `Activity B` or in `Activity A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add finish() in your activity A you should add finish() method after setResult method in activity2 class . You problem will be solved completely

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue completely!